# How to get a specific user data object in Firebase Auth with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to get a specific user data in firebase auth using javascript by a UID (User id). If it's not allowed to get a user by id, at least is there a way to get all users, then i could loop through these users and check if the id of the user equals to that id. Is that possible?

[firebase auth users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8et9.png)

Comment: It's not possible with web and mobile client SDKs.  That's a security problem.  You can only do it on your backend with the Firebase Admin SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Add another `collection` named `users` where you store your desired data in and keep the documents id's in sync with the auth uids.

Comment: I tried that but, for example if i change the displayName of a user in Authentication that will not be changed in Firebase Firestore Collection. How do i handle THAT?

Comment: i am starting to understand there is no other way of doing that. But why would google not supply a solution? its probably a security thing?.. they also made in really confusing with the ADMIN SDK etc. that also means we need a solution for deleting a user ( by admin for example) etc etc...